# HomeController not defined error angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have been using oclazyload to reduce response time. While loading the homeController I can see that it has been loaded in network tab through oclazyload. But the controller is not triggered whie calling the html page. I am getting error like :

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.12/ng/areq?p0=homeController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

my Routes config :

```
 $routeProvider.when('/',
    {

        templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController',
          resolve: 
          { // Any property in resolve should return a promise and is executed before the view is loaded
loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
  // you can lazy load files for an existing module
         return $ocLazyLoad.load('app/components/home/homeController.js');}]}});
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: May or may not be important but I notice that all the router-examples in the ocLaclyLoad-docs use `return` inside the resolve. I.e: `return $ocLazyLoad.load('app/component...`. but you omit the return in your example.

Comment: tried with that also. But no luck yet...